# Why file field button disappeared while uploading file?

Tags: 7, hooks, files

I have installed fresh drupal-7 and create file upload field with manage field with 8M Maximum upload size. when i upload a file 25MB then it is showing error message and file field missing.
**Before upload:**
[image]
**After Upload:**
[image]

After long search i got some links
["exceeded the maximum file size" error even when uploading small files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82544/exceeded-the-maximum-file-size-error)
[File upload error "Files must be less than x MB" despite file being smaller than x](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75541/wont-upload-file-to-file-field)
By these link my problem sorted out but my question. **why the file upload field button  disappeared?**.
**My php.ini settings are**

post_max_size = 24M
upload_max_filesize = 512M

Comment: @Molot if i change my php.ini files configuration 
upload_max_filesize = 24M post_max_size = 24M
and try upload file of 63MB, then also file filed disappeared
i dont have any issue with error message but problem is that why file filed button disappeared.

Comment: After changing in php.ini file i.e, upload_max_filsize=24M and post_max_size =40M and try upload file of 63MB, still file filed disappeared basically i do not have any issue with error message but my problem is why file field disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a default bug in drupal.

you can try this [patch](https://drupal.org/files/core_1489692_file_upload_ajax_message_0.patch) ! your problem will be solved

https://drupal.org/node/1489692

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `upload_max_filesize` larger than `post_max_size` if you are not using any library that takes care for such cases. [Plupload integration](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) with [FileField Sources Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload) can get it managed for you.

Currently you are confusing your Drupal by allowing file upload larger than allowed data size. Given that data posted is file size + metadata size, both always equal to or greater than 0, it makes no sense and Drupal may fail.

Specifically, button disappeared because Form or Field API crashed, and it crashed because you mismatched sizes without providing appropriate handler.