# Drupal File upload only allowing one upload at a time

Tags: files

I'm having a problem with the File widget. I have created a content type with a file field that allows unlimited values. When I upload a file I am expecting to be able to immediately upload another file.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UssiV.gif]

but what actually happens is the upload box disappears, meaning I have to save the node and re-edit it in order to upload another file

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo01i.gif]

both these example have exactly the same content type settings, both running the same version of Drupal. I'm not getting any JS errors or anything. Any ideas on why this is happening? I've even updated all my modules and drupal core and tried disabled all my theme's JS files, still have this issue.

Comment: No idea ... But if you can export the website somewhere I could have a look ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably same issue as here
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/112999

As suggested in the post above,
you should consider [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) and [file field sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources), you'll never look back,
imagine dragging 10 files from your explorer/finder to your form field and uploaden them all at once ... ;)